# What the different between "I started my day with the coffee" or "I started my day with the coffee"

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, past-simple

What the differents between "I started my day with the coffee" or "I started my day with the coffee" are ? and which one is correct?

Comment: There's no difference. Typo?

Comment: @Max, yeah, typo, they're different in the title

Comment: @Max, Nor do I, it's not there, I just read it for some reason, I suggested an edit to fix it though

Comment: @Travis - Really, the best thing to do here is to close the question and wait for the O.P. to clarify. I appreciate your edit, but, in a case like this, I think it's better to wait than guess (unless you saw something I didn't that made you sure it was the article being asked about?)

Answer (score 1):

The difference between...

> 1: *I started my day with coffee.*
>    and
>    2: *I started my day with the coffee.*

...simply concerns whether or not (the specific) coffee has already been mentioned, or is contextually relevant and identifiable (for example, speaker is *pointing* to some of that coffee while speaking).

Note that you could also say *... with **a** coffee* (i.e. - *a **cup of** coffee*). That's effectively the same as using the zero article (i.e. - nothing), except it specifically limits the meaning to a ***single*** cup.

Answer (score 0):

"I started my day with the coffee" is incorrect.

In English, you don't use definitive articles in possessive or description

> I own *a* dog

Instead of

> I own *the* dog

And

> I started the day with (a) coffee

Instead of

> I started the day with *the* coffee

And

> The leaf is an oak leaf

Instead of

> The leaf is the oak leaf.

Comment: It depends on whether or not you are indicating something about *that* coffee (or other example item) in particular.